# Need Python regex for all characters between double quotes after 'returned'

Tags: python, regex

I have an error message response...

```
<HttpError 404 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/di-dtbqquery-us-poc-1/queries?alt=json returned "Not found: Table di-dtbqquery-us-poc-1:lab_auxiliary.antonioTes">`
```

I only need the text between the double quotes: `"Not found: Table ry-us-poc-1:lab_aiary.antes"`

What would the correct regex be for all characters between the double quotes only *after* the `returned` bit in the error message? I have scoured stack overflow trying to find specific regex and haven't had any luck. Can anyone please give me a hand?

Comment: Try [`re.findall(r'returned\s*"([^"]+)"', input)`](http://ideone.com/1pD4bB).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
.*returned "(?P<error_message>.*)"
```

Comment: This has to be dynamic. I am going to be getting many error messages between those quotes and I wont always know what it is.

Comment: Could you provide an example?

Comment: It could be `returned "this message"` or `returned "this new message"` or `returned "this unpredictable message"`. I don't know what the message will be. Catch my drift?

Comment: Writing `(?P<error_message>.*)` creates a named capturing group, with name `error_message` and pattern `.*`. Demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/cZ1sJ9/1)